# What does "1/99 tap" mean in a block diagram?

Tags: block-diagram, fiber-optics

I am still trying to understand the modulator in an optical free space transmitter.

I have found the following block scheme:

[image]

It is from ["Direct-detection free-space laser transceiver test-bed"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/241469069_Direct-detection_free-space_laser_transceiver_test-bed). I am trying to make clear for me each part of this scheme.

What does **1/99 tap** (read) mean?

Comment: It's a 1% fiber coupler (beam splitter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From referenced article:

> The CW master laser output is modulated using two LiNbO3 Mach-Zehnder modulators manufactured by EOSpace.

MZM are the same color and just before the 1/99 tap.

From: [Segmented Mach–Zehnder Modulator With 32-nm CMOS Distributed Driver](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Flexible-Transmitter-Employing-Silicon-Segmented-Huynh-Dupuis/deb69afc5bea9a43edeb1299f5e70071a434077f#page=3)

> Output light from the modulator is tapped 1% for power monitoring, while 99% passes through an optical amplifier (OA).

[image]

The 1/99 tap extracts 1% of the optical power for power monitoring allowing 99% to be output to the next stage.

Answer (score 5):

I'm suspecting that it splits 1% of the power off to the bias control blocks and allows the remaining 99% of the power through.

This site has some description in a somewhat different context:
https://learn.lightbrigade.com/blog/pon/fiber-optic-tap-couplers-for-fttx-systems

> ... tap splitters offer a unique solution for low-density
> installations. These products can taper the split percentages in
> increments ranging from as low as 1/99 percent up to the standard 1:2
> (50/50) types.  With a tap splitter in place, the cable near the first
> subscriber would have a drop cable spliced to the 1% leg of the
> splitter, and the other 99% of the optical power would be transmitted
> down the span.
>
> As each subscriber would have different attenuation
> levels due to the splitter and span variations, a loss budget would
> need to be calculated for each subscriber between the OLT and their
> ONT. The maximum loss allowed per subscriber would vary as the
> distance from the OLT increases.  This — along with splitter
> attenuation differences based on the split percentage — requires
> attention to detail when planning the system.
>
> This first
> subscribers on each fiber would use the 1/99 tap splitters until the
> loss budget required a larger split percentage such as a 2/98
> splitter. The percentages would continue to increase to maintain the
> optical power level at the ONT until the last splitter is installed,
> which would normally be a 1:2 (50/50) split.

Comment: As someone who works with fiber optics every day, this is correct.

Comment: The comment by The Photon is highly valued.  Thank you.